# grid-auto-flow javascript implementation?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a grid-auto-flow algorithm javascript implementation?
Is there a known mathematical or computational algorithm that solves the problem?

I mean, a full implementation, especially dense layout, and not a masonry implementation, that desynchronizes the cells.

The aim here is to make grid dense layout available to environments where more than 40% of site access is done by users having IE 11.

Comment: Have you tried polyfills like https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/ or https://github.com/codler/Grid-Layout-Polyfill

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at them, my searches did not show any of them. Are these available as plain javascript and not as node, typescipt only or other similar technology?

Comment: I think so. Usually polyfills are available global, but even if not, compiling them via babel in node is not hard.

Comment: Must be the lack of samples for such case, but those polyfills fail...

Comment: In Grid-Layout-Polyfill case, IE does not calculate the dense layout, I should provide it. This would have been fine if I had an algorithm. This is one of my questions above.

Comment: Maybe for IE you have to use flex or something even older with working polyfill. Grid is quite new technology and don't expect much support for older browsers.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking to implement a small bin packing algorithm because I need to estimate the future position of some elements and animate them to that place.